# Laravel-Excel export is empty after transforming collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-excel

I have this code that is currently performing a **successful** export:

```
$ncrforms = NCRForm::where('created_at', '>=', (new Carbon('first day of last month'))->toDateString())
                        ->where('created_at', '<=', (new Carbon('last day of last month'))->toDateString())
                        ->get();

Excel::create('ncr_forms', function($excel) use($ncrforms) {
    $excel->sheet('Previous Months Forms', function($sheet) use($ncrforms) {
        $sheet->fromArray($ncrforms);
    });
})->export('xls');
```

The issue here, though, is that I have a couple of columns from my collection that I want to change, and so I have added a step to `transform()` the values:

```
$ncrforms = NCRForm::where('created_at', '>=', (new Carbon('first day of last month'))->toDateString())
                        ->where('created_at', '<=', (new Carbon('last day of last month'))->toDateString())
                        ->get();

$ncrforms->transform(function($form) {
    $form->responsibility = is_null($form->responsibility) ? $form->responsibility : $form->personResponsible->name;
    $form->user_id = $form->user->name;

    return $form;
});

Excel::create('ncr_forms', function($excel) use($ncrforms) {
    $excel->sheet('Previous Months Forms', function($sheet) use($ncrforms) {
        $sheet->fromArray($ncrforms);
    });
})->export('xls');
```

However, the new export is now completely empty - the spreadsheet downloads but nothing is in it.

I am using the Laravel-Excel package to perform the export.

**Why is the export empty after I perform the `transform()` - how can I achieve what I am after where the export isn't empty after modifying the values I need to?**

Comment: dd($ncrforms) before Excel::create() has the desired values ?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild yep - sure does.

Comment: strange.. this is working for me on Laravel 5.5 you could try to track it down.  make  a dd($ncrforms) just before $excel->sheet(...)  and then if that is still valid make a dump of $ncrforms before $sheet->fromArray()

Comment: @shock_gone_wild its valid the whole way through - at every step.